# Webcam is not working

Tags: 13.04, webcam

I am using Dell inspiron n series laptop.I just downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 and now when I open apps like webcam toy on Google chrome I can see nothing but a black screen ! Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because your webcam isn't configured completely as of now, i suggest that you follow this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam), it has all the requisite details for testing your webcam and further configuration for it to work on Ubuntu.